# bash, bc modulo does not work with -l flag

Tags: bash, bc

So I am trying to use `bc` to calculate some logarithms but I also need to use it to calculate the modulus for something. Whilst making my script, I launched `bc` to test it.

Without any flags, `bc <<< "3%5"` of course returns `3`.

But with `bc -l` (loads math library so I can compute logarithms) any calculation of `a%b` returns `0` where `a` and `b` can be any number but `0`.

What's happening?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's because, from the manual:

```
   expr % expr
          The result of the expression is the "remainder" and it  is  com‐
          puted  in  the following way.  To compute a%b, first a/b is com‐
          puted to scale digits.  That result is used to compute a-(a/b)*b
          to  the scale of the maximum of scale+scale(b) and scale(a).  If
          scale is set to zero and  both  expressions  are  integers  this
          expression is the integer remainder function.
```

When you run `bc` with the `-l` flag, `scale` is set to `20`. To fix this:

```
bc -l <<< "oldscale=scale; scale=0; 3%5; scale=oldscale; l(2)"
```

We first save `scale` in variable `oldscale`, then set `scale` to `0` to perform some arithmetic operations, and to compute a `ln` we set `scale` back to its old value. This will output:

```
3
.69314718055994530941
```

as wanted.

Answer (score 9):

You could define a function that works in math mode by temporarily setting `scale` to zero.

I have `bc` aliased like this:

```sh
alias bc='bc -l ~/.bcrc'
```

Thus `~/.bcrc` is evaluated before any other expressions, so you can define functions in `~/.bcrc`. For example a modulus function:

```bc
define mod(x,y) { 
  tmp   = scale
  scale = 0
  ret   = x%y
  scale = tmp
  return ret
}
```

Now you can do modulo like this:

```sh
echo 'mod(5,2)' | bc
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 8):

According to the `bc` manual,

```
   expr % expr
          The result of the expression is the "remainder" and it is computed 
          in the following way.  To compute a%b, first a/b is computed to
          scale digits.   That  result  is used to compute a-(a/b)*b to the 
          scale of the maximum of scale+scale(b) and scale(a).  If scale is
          set to zero and both expressions are integers this expression is 
          the integer remainder function.
```

So what happens is that it tries to evaluate `a-(a/b)*b` using the current `scale` settings. The default `scale` is 0 so you get the remainder. When you run `bc -l` you get `scale=20` and the expression `a-(a/b)*b` evaluates to zero when using 20 fractional digits.

To see how it works, try some other fractions:

```
$ bc -l
1%3
.00000000000000000001
```

To make a long story short, just compare three outputs:

Default `scale` with `-l` enabled (20):

```
scale
20

3%5
0

1%4
0
```

Let's set `scale` to 1:

```
scale=1

3%5
0

1%4
.2
```

Or to zero (default without `-l`):

```
scale=0

3%5
3

1%4
1
```

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, when I use `bc -l`, I have the following functions defined:

```
define trunc(x)   {auto s; s=scale; scale=0; x=x/1; scale=s; return x}
define mod(x,y)   {return x-(y*trunc(x/y))}
```

That should give you a proper `MOD` function, while keeping your scale intact.  Of course, it won't help if you NEED to use the `%` operator for some reason.

(That `TRUNC` function is quite handy too, forming the basis for many other useful functions that are outside the scope of this answer.)

Answer (score 3):

man bc :

> If bc is invoked with the -l option, a math library is preloaded and
>   the default scale is set to 20.

So maybe you should set the scale to 0 :

```
#bc
scale=0
10%3
1
```