# `echo " $1 % 2" | bc -l` doesn't work in the terminal or bash script but `bc` takes these arguments within `bc`

Tags: bash, echo, modulo, bc

I haven't been able to find anything related to this nor can my professor explain what's going on. Below is the problem description:

After quite a bit of debugging following is the bash script to print `odd` or `even`:

```
echo $1
odd_even=$(echo "$1 % 2" | bc -l)
echo $odd_even

if [[ $odd_even -eq 0 ]]
then
echo "even"
else
echo "odd"
fi
```

Following is the output:

```
$ bash logic_ex2.sh 3
3
0
even
```

This is weird because the variable `odd_even` contains `0` while the argument is `3`.

We ran the following command to check whats wrong with the `echo "3 % 2" | bc -l` construction since without using that construction we could get the script working:

```
$ echo "3 % 2" | bc -l
0
```

Then we ran `bc` in the terminal and ran `3 % 2` which gave `1` as the proper output.

Can somebody please explain what is happening here?

Comment: why not `odd_even=$(($1 & 1))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27470274/1072112) as to `bc -l` calculates `a % b` differently from plain `bc` without the `-l`. The quick solution is to set your scale back to zero:

```
$ bc -l <<< "scale=0; 3 % 2"
1
```

But I would probably do this without using `bc` at all, since bash includes sufficient functionality to calculate integer remainders. If all you need is integer math, bash may be good enough on its own.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "$1"
odd_even=$(($1 % 2))
echo "$odd_even"

if [[ $odd_even -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "even"
else
    echo "odd"
fi
```

My results:

```
$ bash remtest.sh 3
3
1
odd
$ bash remtest.sh 4
4
0
even
```

Comment: Thanks @ghoti that works! Your explanation of scale makes sense now. I was i was completely confounded by this, but now everything is clear. I would accept and upvote your answer but i don't have enough reputation..

Answer (score 0):

another option:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$1

if [[ $((var % 2)) -eq 0 ]];
   then echo "$var is even";
   else echo "$var is odd";
fi
```